# How to limit current to a DC motor. (using Arduino and BTS7960)

Tags: arduino, current, motor, dc-motor, current-limiting

I am trying to build a force feedback racing wheel. I have a 250W 24v e-bike motor which I am trying to use for this project. The problem is that the motor draws too much current at the start and also while changing spin direction. I think I have already shorted out the BTS7960 motor driver (as there is continuity between the power pins) so I need to buy a new motor driver.

Ideally, the motor should not draw more than 30amps at any given time. I do not mind if the torque is affected by the current limiting. I have a current sensor that is connected to the Arduino that I use to measure current, the current drawn at startup and changing direction is well over 30amps.

I am new to all of this so I appreciate any help

Comment: How do you know you are drawing too much current?

Comment: I have a current sensor in series with the motor. It sends the current reading to the Arduino.

Comment: _"I have a current sensor that is connected to the Arduino"_ - which current sensor, and how is it connected? What is the motor power supply?

Comment: It is the motor controller's job to limit the current. If you need other current limits, you must modify the controller itself. Adding a separate circuit only for current limiting is not a practical option. If you want to modify the controller, please provide a schematic, if you want to build a controller, you may look for existing solutions to start with. We can help tuning it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing the starting surge of the motor, which can be several times the running current.  You've already got an Arduino and the BTS7960 has a PWM input, so try ramping up the current instead of going full-off to full-on.